# How to fix MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have this code and have problem with Mongo version. Help me to fix this code, please. Thanks!

```
const connectDatabase =( )=>{

    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true,useCreateIndex:true}).then(()=>{
        console.log(`Mongodb connected with server: ${data.connection.host}`);
    }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

downgrade to mongoose v5 or remove this option
set `useCreateIndex` to `false`

```
 mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true,useCreateIndex:false}).then(()=>{
        console.log(`Mongodb connected with server: ${data.connection.host}`);
    }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Can you fix my code follow Mongo version 6 bro?

Comment: I update my answer